# PLM package: Balanced data shown as unbalanced in regression

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

The dataset which I am using here is unbalanced, but I balanced it manually like this by removing the multiple observations for same ID (this is a characteristic of my data as a single household later split to different ones). T is 2 here.

```
 dataset %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(N =n()) %>% filter(N> 2 | N < 2)
```

Then I removed these rogue observations.So now the panel is balanced.I converted them to pdata afterwards

```
  dataset <-plm.data(dataset, 30462)
```

And when I run `is.pbalanced`, it shows TRUE. But the problem is when I run the regression

```
 plm(DEP~ VAR1 + VAR2, data= dataset, model= "within")
```

The summary shows this

> ```
> Unbalanced Panel: n=20236, T=1-2, N=34920
> ```

I don't understand what I am missing here. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Guess: DEP, VAR1 or VAR2 has missing values.

Comment: Compre to what is in `plm_object$model` to your original data so check which observations have been dropped in the estimation. Like Otto Kässi mentioned, likely there are `NA`s.

Comment: BTW: it is better to use `pdata.frame()` than `plm.data()`

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes there are almost 8000 NAs in the Dep variable. This is what is making this unbalanced. I forgot to take this into account.